# How do I show $(1 + x + o(x))^{\frac{1}{x}}$ converges to $e$ as $x \xrightarrow{} 0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

$(1 + x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ has a limit $e$ but what if there is an $o(x)$ term? If the power didn't depend on $x$ then I can use continuity, but it does depend on $x$.

Comment: Try to prove the logarithm has limit $1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to show that $\lim_{x \to 0}{ \log(1+x) \over x} =1$.

Hence, if $f$ is $o(x)$ we have
${ \log(1+x+f(x)) \over x} = { \log(1+x+f(x)) \over x + f(x)} {x+f(x) \over x}$, hence $\lim_{x \to 0}{ \log(1+x+f(x)) \over x} =1$.

If $x \neq 0$, then $(1+x+f(x))^{1 \over x} = e^{\log(1+x+f(x)) \over x} $ from which the limit follows.

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(1+cx)^{1/x} =((1+cx)^{1/(cx)})^c\to e^c$. If $c>1$, then $1+x+o(x)$ is eventually $<1+cx$, hence $\limsup_{x\to 0^+}(1+x+o(x))^{1/x}\le e^c$. As $c$ was otherwise arbitrary, we find $\limsup\le e$. A similar argument works for $\liminf$ as well as for $x\to 0^-$.

Answer (score -2):

This is false, in general. Note that $\sqrt x \in o(x)$, but

$$\lim_{x\to0} (1+x+\sqrt x)^{1/x}=\infty \neq e$$

Comment: $\sqrt{x}\notin o(x)$ for $x\to0$.

Comment: $\sqrt x \in o(x)$ since $\sqrt x < x$ for all $x > 1$. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: I think op is talking about limit towards $0$. You are talking about limit towards infinity.

Comment: oh as $x\to 0$ I see what op means now

Comment: First, we are considering $x\to0$ here. But you are also wrong when you say that $\sqrt{x}\in o(x)$ (I guess when $x\to\infty$ then) *"since $\sqrt{x}<x$ for all $x>1$"*. This inequality is not enough. You are probably confusing Big-O and little-o.

Comment: lol and obviously that $\sqrt x > 0$ and $x>0$ when $x>1$ too but that's obvious. Anyway, op's claim is wrong even when considering it the other way.

Comment: Why? Take logarithm and the limit does equal $1$.

Comment: The problem is not that you omitted to state they are positive... Consider $\frac12x<x$, but $\frac12x\notin o(x)$. You should read the Wikipedia article you linked to more carefully.

Comment: sure but $x^{1/2}$ vs $x^1$. In your example you are taking $x^1$ and $x^1$

Comment: so what functions count? What about like $e^x-3/2$ or something like that? Is that little o as $x\to 0$? because that would make this false.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.